# MySQL driver issue after updating jenkins

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jenkins, jdbc

I have a strange problem.

I updated/upgraded jenkins from Jenkins ver. 1.638 to Jenkins ver. 2.60.1.

One of my jobs now does not work properly anymore.
Its a Maven project.
In the pom following dependency is set:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-p</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now the strange thing is:

When i build this job with Jenkins ver. 1.638 then following driver is set in META-INF/services "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" (java 7 used)

When i build this job with Jenkins ver. 2.60.1 then following driver is set in META-INF/services "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" (java 8 used and must be used, due to system requirements of Jenkins ver. 2.60.1)

I am pretty sure this has something to do with the java version, but i could not figure out the relation.

With this i already tried to force java 7 but this does not solve my problem:

```
<!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <toolchains>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>1.7</version>
                        </jdk>
                    </toolchains>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> -->
```

Full pom.xml:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>JobRunner</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>toolchain</goal>
                        </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <toolchains>
                        <jdk>
                            <version>1.7</version>
                        </jdk>
                    </toolchains>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <finalName>test</finalName>
                    <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                    <workDirectory>target/assembly/work</workDirectory>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                            <directory>src/main/resources/springConfig</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <properties>
        <springVersion>4.2.6.RELEASE</springVersion>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-p</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>sap-jco</groupId>
          <artifactId>sap-jco</artifactId>
          <version>2.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sap</groupId>
            <artifactId>sap-bo-cecore</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1.412</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sap</groupId>
            <artifactId>sap-cesession</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1.412</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sap</groupId>
            <artifactId>sap-bo-celib</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1.412</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sap</groupId>
            <artifactId>sap-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sap</groupId>
            <artifactId>sap-corbaidl</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.1.412</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>sap</groupId>
            <artifactId>sap-ebus405</artifactId>
            <version>11.5.8.834</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ftpserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>ftpserver-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: It is very unlikely that the MySQL JDBC driver would have a reference to the Oracle JDBC driver. Be aware that each JDBC driver will have its own `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file. If you create fat JARs, you need to take care of correctly merging services definitions, instead of just having one overwritten by another (your problem sounds like one of files being processed in a different order). You might want to provide a lot more details, maybe even your full POM and Jenkins definition.

Comment: Mark Rotteveel, thank for your help. I added the pom.xml. What do you mean by jenkins definitions?

Comment: @ Mark Rotteveel you are totally right with your suggestion: Be aware that each JDBC driver will have its own META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file. If you create fat JARs, you need to take care of correctly merging services definitions, instead of just having one overwritten by another (your problem sounds like one of files being processed in a different order).     -- Im now rework this application and i think this will solve my problem. Thank you once again. Best regards Denyo